# Derivation of Coulomb's law from classical field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

In the section on Coulomb's law in QFT by Schwartz, he expands $-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{2}$ to get $-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\mu})^{2}$, can someone please explain how he arrives at the second term in this expression? I am getting this term as $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})(\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu})$.

Comment: Do integration-by-parts twice on that term in the action.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor does the calculation for you. See the calculation under the heading: Lagrangian formulation of classical electromagnetism.